# How to fetch swipe up count from Instagram story insights graph API?

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, facebook-insights

I need to fetch **swipe up** count which show in the insights of Instagram.As Facebook is not providing **swipe up** count through their graph API so how can I get that data.

Scraping won't work as I already did and I want to fetch those data in python or javascript

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now facebook is not providing this data in graph-api and it is only provided in influences in insights so for now its not possible for now to fetch but you can get by web **scraping**

Facebook can provide this data in next version of graph-api

Comment: fine it seams like bad luck for now